# Beam/Dataflow Python: AttributeError: '_UnwindowedValues' object has no attribute 'sort'

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am developing a workflow process to run on Google Cloud Dataflow using the Python SDK from Apache Beam.

When running locally the workflow successfully completes with no errors and the data output is exactly as expected.

When I try to run on Dataflow service, it throws the following error:
`AttributeError: '_UnwindowedValues' object has no attribute 'sort'`

Which is from the following piece of code:

```
class OrderByDate(beam.DoFn):
def process(self, context):
    (k, v) = context.element
    v.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('date'))
    return [(k, v)]
```

And this is called using the standard `beam.ParDo` like so:

```
'order_by_dates' >> beam.ParDo(OrderByDate())
```

The data in the `(k, v)` tuple looks like this example:

```
('SOME CODE', {'date':'2017-01-01', 'value':1, 'date':'2016-12-14', 'value':4})
```

With `v` being the object of dates and values

I have tried switching to a standard lambda function also throws the same error.

Any ideas why this is running differently locally vs on Dataflow? Or suggested work around.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found a solution, I needed to specifically convert `v` to a list `list(v)` before doing the sort, which worked.

Strange the differences between running local vs remote.

Comment: I've added an explanation as to why this is the case in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42283279/1255356

Comment: That helped a lot to me mate. Thanks for sharing!