# What does object of type '_UnwindowedValues' has no len() mean?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm using Dataflow 0.5.5 Python. Ran into the following error in very simple code:

```
print(len(row_list))
```

`row_list` is a list. Exactly the same code, same data and same pipeline runs perfectly fine on DirectRunner, but throws the following exception on DataflowRunner. What does it mean and how I can solve it?

```
job name: `beamapp-root-0216042234-124125`

    (f14756f20f567f62): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 544, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 973, in dataflow_worker.executor.MapTaskExecutor.execute (dataflow_worker/executor.c:30547)
    with op.scoped_metrics_container:
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 974, in dataflow_worker.executor.MapTaskExecutor.execute (dataflow_worker/executor.c:30495)
    op.start()
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 302, in dataflow_worker.executor.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/executor.c:12149)
    def start(self):
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 303, in dataflow_worker.executor.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/executor.c:12053)
    with self.scoped_start_state:
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 316, in dataflow_worker.executor.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/executor.c:11968)
    with self.shuffle_source.reader() as reader:
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 320, in dataflow_worker.executor.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/executor.c:11912)
    self.output(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 152, in dataflow_worker.executor.Operation.output (dataflow_worker/executor.c:6317)
    cython.cast(Receiver, self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 85, in dataflow_worker.executor.ConsumerSet.receive (dataflow_worker/executor.c:4021)
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 766, in dataflow_worker.executor.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowsOperation.process (dataflow_worker/executor.c:25558)
    self.output(wvalue.with_value((k, wvalue.value)))
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 152, in dataflow_worker.executor.Operation.output (dataflow_worker/executor.c:6317)
    cython.cast(Receiver, self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 85, in dataflow_worker.executor.ConsumerSet.receive (dataflow_worker/executor.c:4021)
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 545, in dataflow_worker.executor.DoOperation.process (dataflow_worker/executor.c:18474)
    with self.scoped_process_state:
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 546, in dataflow_worker.executor.DoOperation.process (dataflow_worker/executor.c:18428)
    self.dofn_receiver.receive(o)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 195, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive (apache_beam/runners/common.c:5137)
    self.process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 262, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:7078)
    self.reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 274, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.reraise_augmented (apache_beam/runners/common.c:7467)
    raise type(exn), args, sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 258, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:6967)
    self._dofn_simple_invoker(element)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 198, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._dofn_simple_invoker (apache_beam/runners/common.c:5283)
    self._process_outputs(element, self.dofn_process(element.value))
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 286, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._process_outputs (apache_beam/runners/common.c:7678)
    for result in results:
  File "trip_augmentation_test.py", line 120, in get_osm_way
TypeError: object of type '_UnwindowedValues' has no len() [while running 'Pull way info from mapserver']
```

**code here： trip_augmentation_test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

from __future__ import absolute_import

import argparse
import logging
import json

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.utils.options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.utils.options import SetupOptions


def get_osm_way(pairs_same_group):

  import requests
  from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
  from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
  from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
  import time
  #disable InsecureRequestWarning for a cleaner output
  requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

  print('processing hardwareid={} trips'.format(pairs_same_group[0]))

  row_list = pairs_same_group[1]
  print(row_list)
  http_request_num = len(row_list) ######### this line ran into the above error##########
  with requests.Session() as s:
      s.mount('https://ip address',HTTPAdapter(pool_maxsize=http_request_num))  ##### a host name is needed for this http persistent connection
      pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)

      for row in row_list:
          hardwareid=row['HardwareId']
          tripid=row['TripId']
          latlonArr = row['LatLonStrArr'].split(',');
          print('gps points num: {}'.format(len(latlonArr)))
          cor_array = []
          for latlon in latlonArr:
              lat = latlon.split(';')[0]
              lon = latlon.split(';')[1]
              cor_array.append('{{"x":"{}","y":"{}"}}'.format(lon, lat))
          url = 'https://<ip address>/functionname?coordinates=[{}]'.format(','.join(cor_array))
          print(url)
          print("Requesting")
          r = pool.apply_async(thread_get, (s, url)).get()
          print ("Got response")
          print(r) 
          if r.status_code==200:
              yield (hardwareid,tripid,r.text)
          else:
              yield (hardwareid,tripid,None)


def run(argv=None):
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('--input',
                      help=('Input BigQuery table to process specified as: '
                            'PROJECT:DATASET.TABLE or DATASET.TABLE.'))
  parser.add_argument(
      '--output',
      required=True,
      help=
      ('Output BigQuery table for results specified as: PROJECT:DATASET.TABLE '
       'or DATASET.TABLE.'))

  known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
  pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(argv)
  pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
  p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)  

  (p
    | 'Read trip from BigQuery' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=known_args.input))
    | 'Convert' >> beam.Map(lambda row: (row['HardwareId'],row))
    | 'Group devices' >> beam.GroupByKey()
    | 'Pull way info from mapserver' >> beam.FlatMap(get_osm_way)
    | 'Map way info to dictionary' >> beam.FlatMap(convert_to_dict)
    | 'Save to BQ' >> beam.io.Write(beam.io.BigQuerySink(
            known_args.output,            schema='HardwareId:INTEGER,TripId:INTEGER,OrderBy:INTEGER,IndexRatio:FLOAT,IsEstimate:BOOLEAN,IsOverRide:BOOLEAN,MaxSpeed:FLOAT,Provider:STRING,RoadName:STRING,WayId:STRING,LastEdited:TIMESTAMP,WayLatLons:STRING,BigDataComment:STRING',
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE))
  )
  # Run the pipeline (all operations are deferred until run() is called).
  p.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':   
  logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
  run()
```

**pipeline call here (I'm using Google Cloud Datalab)**

```
!python trip_augmentation_test.py \
--output 'my-project:my-dataset.mytable'  \
--input 'SELECT HardwareId,TripId, LatLonStrArr FROM [my-project:my-dataset.mytable] ' \
--project 'my-project' \
--runner 'DataflowRunner' \   ###  if just change this to DirectRunner, everything's fine
--temp_location 'gs://mybucket/tripway_temp' \
--staging_location 'gs://mybucket/tripway_staging' \
--worker_machine_type 'n1-standard-2' \
--profile_cpu True \
--profile_memory True
```

**Follow up**

I logged the type of `row_list`, turned out, in DataflowRunner, it's  `<class 'apache_beam.transforms.trigger._UnwindowedValues'>`, while in DirectRunner, it's `list`.  Is this an expected inconsistency?

Comment: Can you post the full code for more context?

Comment: code added, eliminated unrelavant function definition and  mosaic some sensitive details

Comment: As a comment, you don't need to run all that profiling - it may slow down your job.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This kind of abstraction is necessary in Big Data systems like Beam / Dataflow (and others). Consider that the number of elements in the *list* could be arbitrarily large.

The `_UnwindowedValues` provides the iterable interface to access this set of elements that could be of any size, and may not be possible to keep whole in memory.

---

The fact that the Direct Runner returned a list is an inconsistency that was fixed a couple versions of Beam ago. In Dataflow, the result from `GroupByKey` does not come in the form of a list, and does not support `len` - but it **is** iterable.

In short, before doing `http_request_num = len(row_list)`, you can coerce it into a type that supports len, e.g:

```
row_list = list(pairs_same_group[1])
http_request_num = len(row_list)
```

**But** consider that the list may be very large.

Comment: Thank you @Pablo, I figured it out myself too, kinda the same idea as yours.... So does this tell us that different runners interpretes code differently?  If that's the case, it'd be better to have a nice documentation explaining the different runner specifications. It was a frustrating experience to dubug it out

Comment: Yup. Sorry about that. We'll fix or document it soon, hopefully.

Comment: Hi @Pablo, I also encountered a similar problem where I have a pipeline with a groupByKey first then CombinePerKey(combine.TopCombineFn(1, key=lambda x: x[1])). Each value is a tuple and I want to sort the values based on the second element in the tuple. It complains that _UnwindowedValues does not support indexing. It is weird that I have to convert the  _UnwindowedValues to list every time. Do you have any better solution to do this. Thanks

Comment: It does not support indexing because it may be arbitrarily large. If you have 100GB of elements under the same key. It's possible to add the feature, but we'll need to be prepared for users having unexpected long reads of lists as they iterate them. - If you'd like to have the feature added, could you email dev@beam.apache.org to request it?

Comment: I got this error on Apache Beam Python 3.6 SDK 2.15.0 after a GroupByKey  on the DataflowRunner (working on DirectRunner) so not completly fixed. I should prob file this on JIRA, but I don't know where exactly to put the issue. Can you give me a pointer Pablo?

Comment: The problem is not the `_UnwindowedValues`, but rather, the inconsistency. You should always see an `_UnwindowedValues`, because you never know how much data you will have for a single key. Sorry about the confusion. Let me know if you'd like to review it anyway.